# set get class in list in c#

Tags: c#, class, get, set

I wrote code below where I use the `Id` to fill in the name.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get { return Name; } set { Name = Id.ToString(); } }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<test> t1 = new List<test>();

            t1.Add(new test() { Id = 1 });
            t1.Add(new test() { Id = 2 });
            t1.Add(new test() { Id = 3 });
            t1.Add(new test() { Id = 4 });
            t1.Add(new test() { Id = 5 });

            Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t1));
        }
    }
}
```

When the code runs, an exception is raised:

> Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown`.

How resolve problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the Name get property, your code says "get the name by calling the Name get property" and the system gets stuck in an infinite loop. Similarly, your set property is telling the system to call the set property again.

Change

```
public string Name { get { return Name; } set { Name = Id.ToString(); }
```

to

```
public string Name { get { return Id.ToString(); } }
```

Comment: A shorter version is `public string Name => $"{Id}";`